# elegant way to convert Object to Specific Number type

Tags: java, guava

```
 Map<String,Object> node = Maps.newHashMap();
 int courseId = ((Number) node.get("d")).intValue();
```

The  node is a map contains key `'d'` and the related value is a `short` Number , the above code is the safe way to convert a `short` to `int` , but the code style is painful . :(

My Question :  Is there a more elegant way to deal with this case , i've searched the `'Guava'` lib , but didn't find anything related .

---

Here i updated the question , the raw data is a json object on zookeeper nodes . after deserialized  , it upcasting values to Object which turn out to be `Map<String,Object>`

Comment: If you want the data as an int, why do you use shorts in the first place? And if your map contains shorts as values, why is it not a Map<String, Short>?

Comment: first , because maybe i have to considerate other interface which accept integer only . second , like a configuration map , it may contains values like String .

Comment: Why not use a JSON library to read the data as JSON? e.g. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) ([friend of Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FriendsOfGuava)) would do this very nicely. e.g. `jsonObject.get("d").getAsInt();`

Answer (score 1):

What if there are not only Short as map value?

This is some kind of universal method:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> node = new HashMap<>();
    int courseInteger = popNumber(node.get("d"));

    // test popNumber method with Integer
    int i = popNumber(5);
    System.out.println(i); // output 5

    // test popNumber method with Short
    short s = popNumber(new Short("23"));
    System.out.println(s); // output 23

    // test popNumber method with Long
    long l = popNumber(2342L);
    System.out.println(l); // output 2342
}

private <Num extends Number> Num popNumber(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Number)
        return (Num) o;

    // you may do smth else if you get not Number or its child 
    // as map value rather to retur null
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you got my point .  `Number`'s convert won't throw a ` RuntimeException` .

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `Object` value is actually a `Short` then the elegant/concise  way would be to cast to `Short`:

```
int courseId = (Short) node.get("d");
```

`short` -> `int` is a "widening" conversion as an `int` has a bigger range, so nothing else is needed. And unboxing is automatically handled for you.

Since you are storing `Object` at the `Map`, I can't see how you might avoid a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Could you update values of your map from Object to Number?

And then:

```
Map<String,Number> node = Maps.newHashMap();
int courseId = node.get("d").intValue();
```

Comment: I'd like to , but some time the result i get is `Object`